# How to match two values independently of their respectiv postions in a string

Tags: regex, perl

I'm searching for the best way to match two values simultaneously.

I'd like to get a true value if both values are in a string but i don't know in which order they appear in the string (e.g. `abcdef` or `bedfa` in case i want to match `a` and `b`)

Is there a better solution (especially if later I would need more complex values to match) than:

```
$string =~ m/(a.*b)|(b.*a)/i
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
$string =~ /a/i && $string =~ /b/i;
```

Comment: I had this version first, but thought it was not elegant.

Comment: @Pit, when elegant is at odds with clear, choose clear. The alternation approach and the look-ahead approach might look more elegant but if I was trying to maintain your code it would take a few seconds longer to understand what the intent of the code was, even if I could understand the mechanics instantly. The two expression approach is more strait forward in what is being done, find both patterns independent of the other.

Comment: You have a point there.I was however also trying to optimise my code in regard of speed and resources usage, and think that one slightly more complex regex expression might be faster than two simple regex expressions combined with a logic and. It might not be the case/be noticeable with such a simple expression but please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Pit, You might be surprised, multiple matches can be faster given some combinations of Perl versions, patterns being matched, and data being matched against. Regexp performance can be hard to predict, and small changes can have a massive impact on performance.

Comment: I changed to this solution due to @Ven'Tatsu's answer.

Answer (score 5):

You can use positive lookahead as:

```
$string =~ /^(?=.*a)(?=.*b).*$/i
```

In general if you want to check the existence of `foo` and `bar` anywhere in the string you can do:

```
$string =~ /^(?=.*foo)(?=.*bar).*$/i
```

And if you want the `foo` and `bar` as separate words and not as substring of any other word, you can add the word boundary as:

```
$string =~ /^(?=.*\bfoo\b)(?=.*\bbar\b).*$/i
```

Later if you want to add the check for existence of `baz` you can just do:

```
$string =~ /^(?=.*\bfoo\b)(?=.*\bbar\b)(?=.*\bbaz\b).*$/i
```

Comment: I'm still having trouble understanding the lookahead but your solution works. Thx

Comment: @Pit: I would recommended you this link: http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html , it has good explanation of lookahead.

Answer (score 3):

To expand from my comments here is a comparison of a few of the solutions presented.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Benchmark qw(cmpthese);

my $two_regexp = q{
    for my $string ('This and that', 'Not that, this!', 'do not match this') {
        if ($string =~ /this/i && $string =~ /that/i) {
            1;
        }
    }
};

my $alternation = q{
    for my $string ('This and that', 'Not that, this!', 'do not match this') {
        if ($string =~ m/(this.*that)|(that.*this)/i) {
            1;
        }
    }
};

my $alternation_no_capture = q{
    for my $string ('This and that', 'Not that, this!', 'do not match this') {
        if ($string =~ m/(?:this.*that)|(?:that.*this)/i) {
            1;
        }
    }
};

my $anchored_lookahead = q{
    for my $string ('This and that', 'Not that, this!', 'do not match this') {
        if ($string =~ /^(?=.*this)(?=.*that).*$/i) {
            1;
        }
    }
};

my $start_anchored_lookahead = q{
    for my $string ('This and that', 'Not that, this!', 'do not match this') {
        if ($string =~ /^(?=.*this)(?=.*that)/i) {
            1;
        }
    }
};

my $free_lookahead = q{
    for my $string ('This and that', 'Not that, this!', 'do not match this') {
        if ($string =~ /(?=.*this)(?=.*that)/i) {
            1;
        }
    }
};

cmpthese(-1, {
    two_regexp               => $two_regexp,
    alternation              => $alternation,
    alternation_no_capture   => $alternation_no_capture,
    anchored_lookahead       => $anchored_lookahead,
    start_anchored_lookahead => $start_anchored_lookahead,
    free_lookahead           => $free_lookahead,
});
```

You should run this with your actual patterns and a sample set of real data, it could radically change the results. Recent versions of Perl have change regexp performance so my results might not be close to your results. On a Perl 5.8.8 box I have handy I get these results.

```
                             Rate free_lookahead alternation alternation_no_capture anchored_lookahead start_anchored_lookahead two_regexp
free_lookahead           170836/s             --        -55%                   -61%               -61%                     -67%       -73%
alternation              378300/s           121%          --                   -13%               -13%                     -27%       -40%
alternation_no_capture   432784/s           153%         14%                     --                -1%                     -17%       -31%
anchored_lookahead       436906/s           156%         15%                     1%                 --                     -16%       -30%
start_anchored_lookahead 518950/s           204%         37%                    20%                19%                       --       -17%
two_regexp               628278/s           268%         66%                    45%                44%                      21%         --
```

So for at least my aesthetic sense and version of Perl using two matches wins both ways.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just this?

```
$string =~ /a/i && $string =~ /b/i
```

It's more legible.