# Perl Regex in an 'if' statement [syntax]

Tags: regex, perl, syntax

Up to now, if I wanted to group together several regex's within an *if* statement, I did it this way:

```
my $data =...
if ($data =~ m/regex/ && $data =~ m/secondregex/) {...}
```

Is there a shortcut (and I'm sure there is; it's Perl!) to avoid repeating $data, something like:

```
if ($data =~ m/regex/ && m/secondregex/) {..}
```

??

Comment: Can you give an example pattern? You should be able to combine both patterns into one.

Comment: Why do you need two regexps? If it is tested with && I bet it can be single expression. [edit] Oh I'm late :) +1 halfdan

Comment: If you combined them into a single regex you would need to combine all the possible orders in which the subpatterns can appear in a single string, generating even more complex regexes to test against. For two regexes it would be `m/^(?:.*regex.*secondregex .*)|(?:.*secondregex.*regex.*)$/` For three or more, it gets ugly.

Comment: Trying to combine two patterns into one very often performs worse than two tests, and the hoops you jump through to get there usually obscures the real intent of the code. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4440725/how-to-match-two-values-independently-of-their-respectiv-postions-in-a-string/4451610#4451610

Comment: @BoltClock: This is a myth. You do not need all possible orderings!!  `/(?=.*REGEX1)(?=.*REGEX2)/s` is not order dependent, and scales linearly. It also works with overlap. All these other solutions fail.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use the default variable `$_` like this:

```
$_ = $data;
if ( m/regex/ && m/secondregex/ ) {..}
```

as regular expressions act on `$_` by default (as many other things in Perl).

Just be certain that you are not in a block where $_ is automatically populated and you will need to use it later in this block. Once it's overwritten it's gone.

Comment: You may want to localize `$_`: `local $_ = $data`

Comment: Assigning to an implicit variable seems like a bit of a hack to me.

Answer (score 18):

```
for ($data) {
    if (/regex/ && /secondregex/) {...}
}
```

Comment: This looks cleaner to me than explicitly assigning to a localized $_ - it's analogous to "with" and similar constructs in other languages.

Answer (score 9):

Only one line using smart match:

```
use 5.010;
if ($data ~~ [qr/regex1/,qr/regex2/]) { ... }
```

Answer (score 3):

One more suggestion. Depending on how long your list of regexes you need to match in one if, and how often you need to do this kind thing, it would make a lot of sense to turn this into a subroutine.

Inspired by ruby's every:

```
sub matchesAll ($@) {
  my $string = shift;
  my $result = 1;
  foreach $_ (@_) {
    $result &&= $string =~ $_;
  }
  $result;
}
```

And then do

```
if (matchesAll $data, $regex1, $regex2, $regex3, $regex4) ...
```

Note: this requires all regexs be compiled for future use using qr// `$regex1 = qr/regex1/`

Answer (score 1):

To add to the list of ways to put `$data` into `$_`:

```
if ( grep { m/regex/ && m/secondregex/ } $data ) {...}
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your structure of if conditions. You may also be able to refactor some of the regular expressions out using nested *if*s.

I.e.: changing

```
if (/regex1/ && /regex2/) block1
elsif (/regex2/ && /regex3/) block2
```

into

```
if (/regex2/){
  if (/regex1/) block1
  else (/regex3/) block2
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to change

```
if (/re1/ && /re2/ && /re3/) { ... }
```

into a single pattern is this way:

```
if (/(?=.*re1)(?=.*re2)(?=.*re3)/s) { ... }
```